# Making an if(x==y) statement in Brainfuck

Tags: if-statement, brainfuck, esoteric-languages

So I'm working on a program that reads in a file and then outputs it back out again but i'm having trouble getting the program to stop taking input at the end of the file. I want it to stop at a specific character like '0' or '$' or anything really since a one character NULL can't be read into my brainf interpreter. Here is the code so far:

```
>+[>,][<.]
```

The problem starts at `[>,]` since the input can never be NULL this loop never ends.

So how can I insert an if statement that will terminate this loop if it ever reaches a pre-specified end character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code is equivalent to your code, except it will stop when the value of the input is 1 (non-printable in ASCII). The `<` between the loops is required because the last value is 0.

```
>+[+>,-]<[<.]
```

It decrements the value after input, checks if it is 0, and loops back if it isn't. If it looped back, it must increment the pointer again to undo the decrement. A sample array might be:

```
00  02  H  e  l  l  o  _  W  o  r  l  d  00
                                          ^
```

However, the `[<.]` prints the reverse of the string (followed by a non-printable 1). The string itself can be printed by moving the pointer to the beginning and moving forward from there, as shown in this code:

```
>+[+>,-]<[<]>>[.>]
```

In this code, the `[<]` stops when it reaches index 0, the `>>` moves to index 2 (string start), and the `[.>]` outputs characters until it reaches the 0 at the end.

If you want to use a different ASCII character, such as space (32), repeat the `+` and `-` within the first loop that many times. (Warning: this code will result in values below 0 if there are any characters less than 32 in your input).

```
>+[++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>,--------------------------------]<[<]>>[.>]
```

Answer (score 3):

Start with your significant character – let’s go for `$`, since it’s ASCII 36:

```
++++++[->++++++<]>
```

Read input, copying both the input and the significant character over twice, with the second significant character at the end:

```
[[->+>>>>+<<<<<]>>,[->+>+<<]
```

for a structure like this:

```
┌───┲━━━━━━━┱───────┬───────┬───┐
│ $ ┃ blank ┃ input │ input │ $ │
└───┺━━━━━━━┹───────┴───────┴───┘
```

Subtract the first `$` from the first `input`:

```
<[->>-<<]>>
```

If it’s not zero, move forwards three times to the empty cell after the copy of `$`, then move backwards unconditionally, exiting the loop when the input was `$` and otherwise leaving you at a `$`, ready to start again:

```
[>>>]<]
```

After the loop, you’re left on the `blank` of the matched character. Move forwards to the matching input character and erase it so it isn’t reprinted, move backwards five times to reach the second-to-last `input`’s intact copy, and keep backing up from there (this doesn’t have to rely on wrapping interpreters and such if you shift forwards a bit at the start):

```
>>[-]<<<<<[<<<<<]
```

And then print them out!

```
>>>>>[.>>>>>]
```

In all,

```
++++++[->++++++<]>
[[->+>>>>+<<<<<]>>,[->+>+<<]<[->>-<<]>>[>>>]<]
>>[-]<<<<<[<<<<<]>>>>>[.>>>>>]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a helpful page full of [BF algorithms](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms) that I like to make use of.

The algorithms you would need are #19 (`x = x==y`) and either #28 (`if (x) {code}`) or #30 (`if (x) {code1} else {code2}`).

Checking whether two cells are equal is pretty easy, so I'll just copy the `if (x) {code1} else {code2}` algorithm here. `temp0` means move to a cell to use as a temporary variable. This specific code does require that `temp0` and `temp1` follow `x` consecutively in memory.

```
temp0[-]+
temp1[-]
x[
 code1
 x>-]>
[<
 code2
 x>->]<<
```